# Solucionar error, Line 17 Incorrect syntax near '27'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

Hola estoy teniendo este problema al intentar ejcutar un procedimiento almacenado, ese es mi prcedimiento en el cual deseo obtener los registros de ciertos empleados entre un limite de tiempo

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[ReporteKardexPorPeriododeTiempoTodo] 
@codigo nvarchar(50),
@fechainicio datetime,
@fechaFin datetime
as 
begin
exec ('select * from REPORTE_QUINCENAL_ASISTENCIA where emp_pin in ( '+ @codigo +' )  and Fecha between ( '+@fechainicio +')   and ('+@fechafin +' )')
end


exec ReporteKardexPorPeriododeTiempoTodo '2,3,4','2018-08-27 14:24:41.000','2018-08-27 14:24:41.000'
```

de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: El error dice que está en la línea 17, tu código tiene menos de esa cantidad

Comment: Sugiero que primero lo hagas por partes, imprime la sentencia y ponla en un print y ya despues vas revisando si sale algun error, parece ser algo de las fechas, hazle un CAST(Fecha as Date) >= '2023-06-01', espero ayude en algo, saludos!!

Comment: Que compilador usas exctamente? tienes un exec con parentesis y otro sin parentesis, posiblemente ahi sea el problema

Comment: Gracias a todos me funciono perfecto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema ocurre porque, en el string que construyes con la consulta las fechas no están encerradas entre comillas.

Esta cadena debe contener una sentencia SQL válida. Es decir, una sentencia que podrías introducir directamente en Management Studio ejecutar allí sin errores.

Podrás notar el error si, en lugar de ejecutar directamente, imprimes el valor, por ejemplo, si cambias tu procedimiento almacenado a:

```
begin
  print 'select * from REPORTE_QUINCENAL_ASISTENCIA where emp_pin in ( '+ @codigo +' )  and Fecha between ( '+@fechainicio +')   and ('+@fechafin +' )';
end
```

Esta versión a mi aún me genera error, pues SQL no convierte las fechas de manera automática a string, pero aún convirtiéndolas:

```
begin
  print 'select * from REPORTE_QUINCENAL_ASISTENCIA where emp_pin in ( '+ @codigo +' )  and Fecha between ( '+cast(@fechainicio as nvarchar) +')   and ('+ cast(@fechafin as nvarchar) +' )';
end
```

A mi me imprime una sentencia no válida:

```
select * from REPORTE_QUINCENAL_ASISTENCIA where emp_pin in ( 2,3,4 )  and Fecha between ( Aug 27 2018  2:24PM)   and (Aug 27 2018  2:25PM )
```

Por otro lado, además de agregar las comillas faltantes, sugiero que utilices la función `convert()` para asegurarte de darle a la fecha el formato adecuado y que incluya la información de horas, minutos, segundos y milisegundos (si estos son importantes para tu proceso).

Tomando en cuenta esto, podrías declarar tu SP, por ejemplo así:

```
alter procedure [dbo].[ReporteKardexPorPeriododeTiempoTodo] (
    @codigo nvarchar(50)
  , @fechainicio datetime
  , @fechaFin datetime
)
as 
begin
  declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'select * from REPORTE_QUINCENAL_ASISTENCIA where emp_pin in ('+ @codigo +') and Fecha between '''+ convert(nvarchar, @fechainicio, 121) +''' and '''+ convert(nvarchar, @fechafin, 121) +'''';
  print @sql;
  exec (@sql);
end;
go
```

Ves que aún he dejado la sentencia `print` para que, al declararlo, puedas ver la sentencia dinámica antes de que se ejecute.

Si todo está bien, ya para producción, quítale esa línea.

En la salida de mensajes, esta versión ya imprime una sentencia válida:

```
select * from REPORTE_QUINCENAL_ASISTENCIA where emp_pin in (2,3,4) and Fecha between '2018-08-27 14:24:41.000' and '2018-08-27 14:24:41.000'
```

Answer (score 1):

El error sucede porque estás intentando usar el operador `IN` de MSSQL utilizando variables en la consulta.

[Microsoft SQL - IN (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Lo que necesitas hacer es utilizar una sentencia MSSQL dinámica:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE ReporteKardexPorPeriododeTiempoTodo
    @codigo NVARCHAR(50),
    @fechaInicio VARCHAR(50),
    @fechaFin VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)   
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM REPORTE_QUINCENAL_ASISTENCIA WHERE emp_pin IN (' + @codigo + ') AND Fecha BETWEEN CAST(' + @fechaInicio + ' AS DATE) AND CAST(' + @fechaFin + ' AS DATE)'
    EXEC (@SQL)
END

EXECUTE ReporteKardexPorPeriododeTiempoTodo @codigo='2,3,4', @fechaInicio="'2023-06-01'", @fechaFin="'2023-06-02'"
```

De esta forma podrás utilizar variables dinámicas en tus consultas.

[Dynamic SQL in Synapse SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-dynamic-sql)